# SQL Problems Trying to get the right info?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
1.SELECT T.TrackTitles, A.EntryDate
    FROM Tracks 
    JOIN Titles USING (TitleID)
    JOIN Artists USING (ArtistID)
    WHERE (A.EntryDate > “October 1, 2003”);

2. SELECT TrackTitles, EntryDate
        FROM Tracks
        WHERE (EntryDate>ALL
        (SELECT EntryDate 
         FROM Artist
         WHERE EntryDate = “October 1, 2003”));
```

Hey guys so I have these two queries but I'm having a hard time getting the right info.
the first query Im trying to Find the trackTitles of all tracks recorded by artists which were entered into the database (that is, have entrydates) after October 1, 2003.  Use one or more joins; 
do not use any subqueries.

The second I'm trying to find the same data selected in the last question.  This time, use one or more subqueries and do *not* use any joins.

Comment: The first is close, try fix two issues: 1) which is A? Which is T? 2) which format is the entrydate?

Comment: Which is it, MySQL or SQL Server?  Avoid `USING`, as it'll trip you up on real queries on production dbs (wrong comparisons, or wrong columns).  What is the actual result of running these queries, and what should the results really be?

Comment: Its MySQL Clockwork Muse so should I use  ON or IN instead

Comment: You have to use `ON` to specify a condition for a join, of which `IN` can be one.  Can we get the layout, and some small sample data, for your tables?  Subqueries act as scoping in SQL, and only return the specified columns to the portion of the query in which they're used (ie, in a `WHERE` clause, they're only available for the condition).  You'd be better off using ISO format for dates (`'YYYY-MM-DD'`).  Please edit your question to remove the SQL Server tags, as that's a different product (although answers should work equally well for both in this case).

Comment: Here is my SQL table format you can take a look at that and I did format the entrydatae like that @Clockwork-Muse:

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1129171043767079&set=a.101374013213459.3317.100000225824255&type=1&theater

Comment: So should I use ON @Clockwork-Muse or IN

Comment: That kind of information belongs in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following queries:

1)

```
SELECT tr.TrackTitles, ar.EntryDate
FROM Tracks tr
INNER JOIN Titles ti on tr.TitleID = ti.TitleID
INNER JOIN Artists ar on ar.ArtistID = ti.ArtistID
WHERE (ar.EntryDate > '2003-10-01');
```

2)

```
SELECT tr.TrackTitles, (Select EntryDate from Artists where ArtistID in
                          (Select ArtistID from Titles where TitleID = tr.TitleID)
                       )
FROM Tracks tr
WHERE tr.TitleID in (Select TitleID from Titles where ArtistID in 
                       (Select ArtistID from Artists where EntryDate > '2003-10-01')
                    )
```